# How can I add a serverstamp of type FieldValue to my already exsisting map of typ <String, Dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method which is supposed to add a server timestamp to every document set.

```
  Future<void> _setDocument(String path, {Map<String, dynamic> inputData}) async {
    final outputData = {'createdAt':FieldValue.serverTimestamp()};
    outputData.addAll(inputData)
    try {
      final DocumentReference documentReference = fireStore.document(path);
      return documentReference.setData(outputData);
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      throw UserFriendlyException('Operation Failed', error.message);
    }
  }
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
{Map<String, String> inputData}
The argument type 'Map<String, String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, FieldValue>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

So how could I add the maps together?

**Edit**

Even casting doesn't appear to work

```
final outputData = Map.castFrom<String, FieldValue, String, dynamic>({'createdAt':FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
outputData.addAll(inputData);
```

it throws he following error

```
'CastMap<String, FieldValue, String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' of 'other'
```

Comment: Try casting `outputData` to `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: final outputData = Map.castFrom<String, FieldValue, String, dynamic>({'createdAt':FieldValue.serverTimestamp()}); works! Thanks could you answer so I can accept?

Comment: O nvm it doesn't work when I try to combine the maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without declaring the type, `outputData` is inferred as a `Map<String, FieldValue>`

Instead, you'll want to declare the type of `outputData`

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> outputData = {
  'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
};
```